# Print a list of attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object, printing

Brand new coder here. So this is my test code:

```py
class Dog:
   def __init__ (self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

dog1 = Dog('Peter', 15)
dog2 = Dog('Grayson', 15)

dogs = [dog1, dog2]
```

I want to print a list of all dogs aged 15. What would be the proper way to do so?

Comment: Iterate over `dogs` with a for loop, and access the variable's `age` attribute. You man want to start with `for dog in dogs:`. Give it a try ;)

Comment: So you have a list of many and jusy want to print the ones that their age is 15 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
print(*(dog.name for dog in dogs if dog.age == 15), sep='\n')
```

Which will print the names of the dogs aged 15 on separate lines:

```
Peter
Grayson
```

To keep it as a list:

```
print([dog.name for dog in dogs if dog.age == 15])
# ['Peter', 'Grayson']
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to print the name when you print the dog variable (d) you will want to put this in your Dog class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

Then use:

```
print ([d for d in dogs if d.age == 15])
```

The statement above is the same as:

```
for d in dogs:  # iterates through the dogs list
    if d.age == 15:
        print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

for your example you can do like this:

```
for dog in dogs:  
    if dog.age == 15:
        #just print name of dog
        print(dog.name)
        #print the dog object
        print(dog)
```

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 d = [i.name if i.age == 15 else -1 for i in dogs]
```

'd' is a list of dogs names with age 15.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this approach:

```
dogs=[]
dogs.append( Dog('Peter', 15) )
dogs.append( Dog('Grayson', 15) )
dogs.append( Dog('Boston', 1) )

dogs_aged_15 = [dog for dog in dogs if dog.age == 15]

for dog in dogs_aged_15:
  print(dog.name)

# Peter
# Grayson
```